# Dyntopo erasing image texture/affecting UV map?

Tags: sculpting

After using Dyntopo after having used image texture on the plain, the sculpting tool with Dyntopo destroys the image texture (notice the white spot below Stop) Any idea why?
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dyntopo creates geometry ("dynamic topology") on the fly during sculpting.  The new geometry is not UV mapped yet, so it can't correctly display anything that relies on UV mapping (like most image textures).

[image]

In this example Suzanne's geometry has been subdivided, triangulated, and in the UV Editing workspace a ColorGrid image texture's been set up.  Note the area labeled "FE".

[image]

Above, in the Sculpting workspace, the Dyntopo checkbox has just been enabled.  Note the warning pop-up.

[image]

Above, after Dyntopo sculpting over the "FE" area.  Back in the UV Editing workspace, on the right we can see the new geometry created, while on the left we can see the hole this made in the UV map.  The hole in the UV Map means the corresponding geometry no longer shows the image texture.

*Edited to add* - “Is there no way to see the image texture while you sculpt?” has been asked below.  Yes there is, but how effectively for your purposes?

[image]

[image]

The above pics have a plane with an issue similiar to yours, using a ColorGrid image texture.

[image]

In the pic above the Texture Coordinate node's output used is now Object (instead of UV).  Note the adjustments made to the Mapping node's settings -- **these will be different depending on your needs.**

[image]

In the pic above we see this method used on the Suzanne from earlier -- since this isn't being used on a mostly-flat plane there's significantly more distortion on two of the three axises.  Also, the mapping node settings needed to approximate the earlier example are different.

[image]

Comment: Seconded- sculpt, retopologize, then un-wrap, in that order. Un-wrapping/texturing is always last

Comment: Is there no way to see the image texture while you sculpt?

Comment: I've added to my answer, does that help?

Comment: Did I answer your question?  If so, I'd appreciate a checkmark, if not can you say what more you need?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. To be honest, not sure. I would have to go and test, but would you suggest re-Unwrapping UV after Dyntopo has been done in order to fix the missing texture problem? Or the other solution seems to be using Object output instead of UV from Texture Coordinate shader?

Comment: Dyntopo damages/destroys existing UV mapping, therefor it's considered best practice to UV map after sculpting with it (or after retopologizing over the sculpting).  When sculpting an existing object that's already UV mapped and has an image texture, most people would either ignore the image texture getting patchier or remove it before sculpting.  You've a special case of minimally sculpting a plane, you can keep your image texture in sight as I've shown above, by using the Texture Coordinate node's Object output instead of its UV output.